# Rerender of select list throws validation error on required field

Tags: visualforce, lightning, rendering

I have a vf page with drop down to select the activity type : Task/Event and display the fieldset accordingly. 
When I Change the type the required fields throws errors. I added action region and still not works.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Activity Type">
    Select type Of Activity
    <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedactivitytype}" required="true">

        <apex:selectOptions value="{!selectactivytype}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getactivitytype}" reRender="Taskdetails,eventdetails" />
    </apex:selectlist>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:outputPanel id="Taskdetails">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Task Details" id="taskdetailsection" columns="2" rendered="{!IF(selectedactivitytype == 'Task',true,false)}">

        <apex:repeat value="{!$Objecttype.Task.fieldsets.Recurring_Task}" var="fl">
            <apex:actionRegion>

                <apex:inputfield value="{!Task[fl]}" required="{!fl.required}" />
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageblocksection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs1" title="Recurrence">

        <apex:inputfield value="{!task.isrecurrence}" rendered="{!selectedactivitytype=='Task'}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="messageBox,taskdate" status="spinnerStatus" />
        </apex:inputfield>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputpanel>
<apex:outputpanel id="eventdetails">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Event Details" id="eventdetailsection" columns="2" rendered="{!IF(selectedactivitytype=='Event' , true, false)}">

        <apex:repeat value="{!$Objecttype.Event.fieldsets.Recurring_Event}" var="fl">
            <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Event[fl]}" required="{!fl.required}" />
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageblocksection>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!event.isrecurrence}" rendered="{!selectedactivitytype=='Event'}">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="messageBox,eventdate" status="spinnerStatus" />
        </apex:inputfield>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:outputpanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the controller code as well?

Comment: @ideasforce: I have fixed it. I did a mistake i had to put the action region around the action support instead of input field. Thanks.

Comment: pragii - you should post an answer as a service to the community